how i can give dashed divider between to the two container in flutter with out using any external package
I want to give a divider between two container I generally use a divider or Container border i can try it but using divider i can not give a dashed dashed border in flutter.
Divider(
height: 1,
color: Colors.grey.shade200,
thickness: 1,
indent : 1,
endIndent : 1,
);

without any external package? you have to draw it by yourself using CustomPaint

Try to use below class for divider line
 class SeparatorLine extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        final boxWidth = constraints.constrainWidth();
        const dashWidth = 10.0;
        final dashCount = (boxWidth / (2 * dashWidth)).floor();
        return Flex(
          children: List.generate(dashCount, (_) {
            return SizedBox(
              width: dashWidth,
              height: 1,
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
              ),
            );
          }),
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

and use it as SeparatorLine()
